# Flowchart Tikz for Process with levels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, hyperref, tikz-styles, python

i need a PDF with a huge Process and levels for the subprocesses. The idea is to make it with tikz, but i dont know how to build it simple and automatic. Something like this [example](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/android/) and the package hyperref was my first thought. But the example seems to be little to complicated and error prone for big processes. (My expertise ist not the best with tikz)

Maybe some of you have a better idea how to solve it. Or maybe you know a better solution than tikz.
About some support I would be happy :)

Here an example what i need.

First page is the big Process
[image: First page]

If you doubleclick the Big Process the pdf jumps to the second page.
[image]

In the left top corner you can see the source. If you clkick on the source u come back to the master process.

A double click at one of the processes will open a new level.
For example like this.

[image]
At the bottom you can see an output. If you click it you get to Process 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

[image]

These three pages all link to each other as follows:

- The text 'Big Process' on page 1 links to page 2.
- The text 'Big Process' on page 2 links to page 1.
- The text 'Process 1' on page 2 links to page 3.
- The text 'Big Process' on page 3 links to page 1.
- The text 'Process 1' on page 3 links to page 2.

The linking was achieved using `hyperref` and specific page numbers. If you do

```
\hyperlink{page.1}{text}
```

then in the document the word 'text' appears and clicking it links to page 1.
Now that we can do links we just need to draw the flow chart.
To do this I defined a style:

```
\tikzset{box/.style={draw=borderColour, very thick, fill=#1, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=2cm, text=white}}
```

which, when used like `\node[box=colour] at (x, y) {text}` makes a rectangular node centred at `(x, y)` with width 4cm and height 2cm (unless the text goes out of this range, then it will be the size of the text). This box is filled with whatever colour we put for `colour` and the box has borders which are the colour of `borderColour`.
This brings us to the colours defined for this flowchart (requires `xcolor` for the `html` colour model):

```
\definecolor{borderColour}{HTML}{2f528f}
\definecolor{myBlue}{HTML}{4472c4}
\definecolor{myOrange}{HTML}{ed7d31}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{92d050}
```

These were taken from the example provided.
Finally I defined a style for the connecting arrows:

```
\tikzset{connect/.style={->, >=latex, ultra thick, borderColour}}
```

Now that we have these we simply need to put these elements together in the desired way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

% Define colours
\definecolor{borderColour}{HTML}{2f528f}
\definecolor{myBlue}{HTML}{4472c4}
\definecolor{myOrange}{HTML}{ed7d31}
\definecolor{myGreen}{HTML}{92d050}

% Define tikz styles
\tikzset{box/.style={draw=borderColour, very thick, fill=#1, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=2cm, text=white}}
\tikzset{connect/.style={->, >=latex, ultra thick, borderColour}}

\begin{document}
    ~  % Needed so \vfill doesn't get absorbed
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[box=myBlue] at (0, 0) {\hyperlink{page.2}{Big Process}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \newpage
    Source: \hyperlink{page.1}{\textcolor{myBlue}{Big Process}}
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[box=myOrange] (P1) at (0, 0) {\hyperlink{page.3}{Process 1}};
            \node[box=myOrange] (P2) at (0, -5) {Process 2};
            \node[box=myOrange] (P3) at (0, -10) {Process 3};
            \draw[connect] (P1) -- (P2);
            \draw[connect] (P2) -- (P3);
            \draw[connect] (P3.east) -- ++(2, 0) -- ++(0, 10) -- (P1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
    \newpage
    Source: \hyperlink{page.1}{\textcolor{myBlue}{Big Process}} / \hyperlink{page.2}{\textcolor{myOrange}{Process 1}}
    \vfill
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node[box=myGreen] (SP1) at (0, 0) {Sub-Process 1};
            \node[box=myGreen] (SP2) at (0, -5) {Sub-Process 2};
            \node[box=myGreen] (SP3) at (0, -10) {Sub-Process 3};
            \draw[connect] (SP1) -- (SP2);
            \draw[connect] (SP2) -- (SP3);
            \draw[connect] (SP3.east) -- ++(2, 0) -- ++(0, 5) -- (SP2);
            \draw[connect] (SP2.west) -- ++(-2, 0) -- ++(0, 5) -- (SP1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \vfill
\end{document}
```

The result is then

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Dear @Willoughby thank you for spending time to answer my question. Your desrcibed it really nice so it is easy to understand :)
But I have one question in your solution. It is working fine but it is hardcoded (for example \hyperlink{page.2}{Big Process}). It will go to page 2. If I now add something new before page 2 it will be linked to the wrong page.
Do you think it is possible to link it to the boxes and not to the pages?

Comment: Have a look at the `\hypertarget` command

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will have a look at it